# How to stop a:link from being applied to all links

Tags: html, css

I have the following css that is used to make one link coloured but it applies to all of the links I have. Is there any way to stop this.

This is my css that is getting applied to the links:

```
a:visited {
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-style: italic;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFF;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #F00;
display: block;
border-radius: 5px;
z-index:10;
}

a:link {
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-style: italic;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFF;
text-decoration: none;
background-color:#F00;
display: block;
border-radius: 5px;
z-index:10;
}

a:hover {
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-style: italic;
font-weight: bold;
color: #CCC;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #C00;
display: block;
border-radius: 5px;
z-index:10;
}
```

This is the link that it is suppose to get applied to:

```
<td><a href="Food.html">Food</a></td>
```

This is the link that I don’t want it to get applied to:

```
<td class="footer"><b><a href="Rides.html">Top Attractions</a></b>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could select your `a` tag by the `href` like this:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cw18hp5o/)**

```
a[href="Food.html"] {
    color: red;
}
```

**Updated: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aa0a30L3/)** (with your codes)

Answer (score 1):

Working JSfiddle: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m7scwxhd/)

I gave the link you wanted to style a class and gave the class a style.

```
a.food :visited
```

instead of a:visited

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

```
<td><a href="Food.html" class="colored>Food</a></td>
```

CSS

```
 .colored{
color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do, would be to give the  tag an id/class and then refer to that in your css.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class to the link you want different and style it separately.

HTML:

```
<td class="footer"><b><a href="Rides.html" class="rides">Top Attractions</a></b>
```

CSS:

```
a.rides {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply a class to the links you want to effect:

```
<a href='food.html' class='apply_to_this'>Food</a>
```

Then in your CSS:

```
a:link.apply_to_this{
    // your styles
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the links you wan't to apply this rule, or you can use this rule :

```
a:not(.footer):link {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than stopping it being applied to one link, you need to add a class to that link with additional CSS that overrides the styles you want to change, or (though this is bad practice...) use inline styles on that one link.

**Proper solution:**

In your CSS

```
.exception {put css here that will override the general link css, using !important to override it ifnecessary}
```

In your html

```
<a href="food.html" class="exception">Content here</a>
```

**Quick and dirty solution**

```
<a href="food.html" style="Your overiding css here">Content</a>
```

Though this way will work, it is rightly frowned upon for accessibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a class and apply it to that link like mentioned above or you can just follow through your selectors to tell CSS to apply that link code to only a:links within those selectors like I've posted below:

```
#mainContainer #footer #etc #etc a:link {
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-style: italic;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFF;
text-decoration: none;
background-color:#F00;
display: block;
border-radius: 5px;
z-index:10;
}
```

PS - Inline styles are very bad practice. It adds tons of extra code that will reduce your rankings for Google, Yahoo, MSN, etc. Not to mention it makes code harder to read and more clunky.